# New version import.io cannot create API

Tags: import.io

I have a number of APIs both authenticated and not authenticated, created in earlier versions of import.io.

With the new Windows app I can't create an API, or at least pick one up. The tutorial shows a whole bunch of options, but I only get "CONFIGURE" and "EXPORT". "Configure" only gives me the option of single URL, bulk extract and URLs from another API. But there is no link to give me the API address.

Similarly, EXPORT only provides "USE IN DATA SET".

I asked their support but got this:

> Hi Glenn,
>
> Thank you for reaching out.
>
> As you may noticed, we made some changes to our interface.
>
> We moved the into the Export tab (next to configure) and named it
>   simple API integration.
>
> Let me know if you have any questions.
>
> Thank you,

But when I replied that I don't have that option, I got no reply.

What am I doing wrong?

Glenn.

Comment: Hi Glenn, Sorry you did not get a follow up with support. Would you mind posting a screenshot of what you are seeing? Have you attempted to re-download the app? Let me know, thanks!

Comment: Hi @meg-ainsley, I took a screen video of what I was trying to do and resubmitted the ticket to importio. They acknowledged there was a bug with the new app version. Waiting further instructions. But I can close this request now, but I'll leave it up here for others to know there's a bug.The video is at [my evernote account](http://www.evernote.com/l/AAhMJsy7INVHFauEOGFQBgEgJq2IPRSA6AU/).

Answer (score 0):

Import.io support got back t me after I sent a screen video (http://www.evernote.com/l/AAhMJsy7INVHFauEOGFQBgEgJq2IPRSA6AU/). There's a bug in the new Windows desktop app that prevents authenticated APIs from showing.

Comment: Thanks for posting this as an answer! We will be sure to keep you to up-to-date as this is fixed. Thanks, Meg.